# How to use step_counter sensor when the screen goes off on OREO?

Tags: android, background-process, android-sensors, android-8.0-oreo, android-wake-lock

I'm developing a step counter on android and i've a little problem with android oreo.

I've a foreground service that detect and count steps.

The problem is counting steps when the app is in background and the screen is off. With the other versions of Android, i had bypass this problem with wakelocks, but seems that wakelocks are blocked on android oreo.

And there is the problem, i can't use any sensor like accelerometer or step_counter when screen is off

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: The only way i found, is to use the Google's step counter apis.. And let know the user that the app/service need to run in background, so the user need to whitelist the app in the power settings.. I've found this site, it can be useful to know on witch smartphone you will have problems with background services https://dontkillmyapp.com/